# Problem with redirect using 'fetch' from frontend page

Tags: node.js, redirect, fetch, response

I am using the following JS in a webpage to send information to a Node.js server upon 'clicking' on an image in the webpage, I am having trouble with the 'redirect' once the 'fetch' is executed:

```
fetch('/members/pages/callup', {
 method: 'post',
 headers: {
   'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 },
 body: JSON.stringify({name: splits[1], presence: available, str: 'Some string: &=&'})
})
.then(function(res) {res.json()})
.then(function(res) { 

 if(res.response) {
 redirect: window.location.replace("/members/pages/" + splits[1]); 
 } else {
 alert("Error in the response");
 }

}) 
.catch(function(err) {
alert("Error in the fetch call..." + err);
})
```

The fetch seems to properly send the 'body' data to the server.  However I am getting the following error:  "Error in the fetch call...TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined"...

The server performs a database call using the information sent by the frontend, and I thought all I needed to do was to send a "200 (OK)" response back...here is the server code:

```
app.post('/member/pages/callup', jsonParser, function (req, res) {

console.log("I RECEIVED FROM CLIENT THE FOLLOWING:");
console.log(req.body);  //works fine, prints output from frontend 'fetch' to console...

  db.lookupMember(req.body.name)
  .then(function(foundUser) {

  console.log('Async success!', foundUser);  //works fine, prints database info to console... 

   if (typeof foundUser != "undefined") {
   res.sendStatus(200);  //trying this to 'reply' back to 'fetch' in frontend...is this not correct? 
   }  //'foundUser' is NOT'undefined'...

  })
  .catch(function(error) {
  console.log('UNABLE TO RETRIEVE MEMBER INFORMATION FROM THE DATABASE...' + error);
  res.redirect('/');  //route to splash page...
  });

})
```

Any suggestions appreciated, this has gone from a minor irritant to a major problem.  I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues in the code. If fixed, code should work fine.

- You `forgot to return res.json() from the function` at one place. Make it `return res.json()` and it will work fine (Inside fetch, 1st then). Due to not returning, res is undefined which is giving the error
- You are trying to use `res.response` but res is not send as a proper json from node server. This will fail at res.json(). You should be doing something like `res.send({response: true})`
- After the if loop in server there is syntax error. It needs to be `redirect =` instead of `redirect:`. Also redirect is not declared anywhere which. (Note: you might not need redirect variable here, simply window.lo... should also work)

Note: Have updated the original answer after having the discussion with OP

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  That is a nice catch, would not have remembered that.  My 'first' .then() statement now reads ".then(function(res) {return res.json()})".  However I now see an error that reads "Error in the fetch call...SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0"...

Comment: In the if block for res.response, it needs to be `redirect =` ... not `redirect:`

Comment: I still get that same error after changing to 'redirect =', which is "Error in the fetch call...SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0".  I then simply removed the first '.then()' statement, since I am not even sure if it is necessary...and now I get an "Error in the response" error message...not sure what to make of it.

Comment: Try printing the `res` in the 1st then or check the API response. It might be improper json and so not getting converted properly

Comment: Since I am not returning json, only a status code (200) would that be causing the issue...?

Comment: I changed the response in my server code.  I now send back "res.send("ALL OK")" and the error changes to "Error in the fetch call...SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0"...since it reports the "A" and previously the "o" it seems my response is not proper...?

Comment: Looking at the docs at "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response" to try to find examples of this usage...cannot seem to find any that utilize 'redirect'...does anybody know of some example pages?

Comment: Yes. Try sending a valid json in res.send such as `{"response":"ok"}` and do the changes discussed above

Comment: Yes I got it already...I changed my response to be an object... "res.send({ message: 'success', response: true })"...seems to have helped correct the issue...thank you for you suggestions.

Comment: @Pangit, Have updated my answer as per the discussion

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  The main issue, as I had originally suspected ...was a faulty response from the server back to the client, as per my previous comment.  Thank you again.